# Strange Holomorphic Function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be holomorphic function on unit disk and it is continuous on boundary of
the disk.
It is well-known that $f$ is constant and equal to zero if $f$ is vanishing on sub-arc
of boundary (Maximum Principle + Reflection theorem)

Also, if real part Re$f$ is vanishing on whole boundary then we also know $f$ is constant by open mapping thm.

However, can we construct a "non-constant" such function $f$ satisfying real part Re$f$ is vanishing only on sub-arc of boundary?

Thank you.

Comment: Any comment would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Could you explain why it follows from the open mapping theorem that $f$ is a constant  when Re$f$ is vanishing on whole boundary? If $f$ is not a constant then it is open...and then?